# SAS Enterprise Guide 8.3 - Show Export Step code in process flow?

Tags: sas

I'm trying see if I can edit or even just view the code that is run when you select Share -> Export as step in project.

The GUI allows me to pick a network/shared drive location, and the export works fine.
But I can't get a standard proc export step to work successfully with the windows fileshare path - it errors with the unix server application path PLUS the windows network path provided within the export parameters.

I suspect it's how our servers are set up with limited access to the wider network, but I know the GUI-driven export is successful, so just want to see how it's handling the paths/navigating network locations to see if we can replicate using code.

Thanks

Comment: As @Tom mentions you need to provision the server with access to the file location required and then you can code this step. The Client interface has access to drives that each user has and that works but the Server itself doesn't. What is actually happening is the file is created on the server and then downloaded to the folder. To code this step in the server only you need the Server to have access to the folder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise Guide is a client/server mode of operation.  When you use the EXPORT node it actually uses the client (your PC) to write to your Windows location.

When you try to run PROC EXPORT it runs that as regular SAS code on the SERVER.  So you would need to allow the server to have access to the location where you want the file written.

You might want to look into the functionality of the SAS PC FILES server tool.  That is another Windows program that you can run that PROC EXPORT can connect to and send data to be written on disks connected to the machine where that PC FILES server process is running.  I think this only works for Microsoft file formats like EXCEL or ACCESS.

Comment: Thank you - whilst not the answer I was hoping for, that does clarify why the difference! Unfortunately PC file servers not an option with our current set up.